# SQL query for finding records where dont have certain value

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have

table A

```
a_id 
a001
a002
a003
a004
a005
```

table B

```
a_id | status | user_id
a001 | 0      | u001
a001 | 1      | u002
a001 | 2      | u003
a002 | 1      | u001
a002 | 0      | u002
a002 | 0      | u003
a003 | 0      | u002
a003 | 0      | u003
a004 | 0      | u001
```

I want to get 
`a003` and `a004` and `a005`

because `a003`,`a004`,and `a005` dont have status 1 and 2

how can i do this?

Comment: What does "get a003 and a004" mean?  Can you provide an example of the output that you're looking for?

Comment: So you want a_ids with status only 0? That is what you meant by 'get a003 and a004' ?

Comment: i want to get result

a003,a004

Comment: yes, i want a_id with status only 0

Comment: What is the purpose of table A?  If an `a_id` appears in table A, but not table B, then is it considered as a match?

Comment: I hope it helps you: `select * from tblB where status = 0 and a_id not in (select a_id from tblB where status<>0)`

Comment: if an a_id appear in table A but not table B then it considered as a match too, i'll fix my question,thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT 
*
FROM tableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tableB b WHERE b.status <> 0 AND a.a_id = b.a_id)
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tableB b WHERE b.status = 0 AND a.a_id = b.a_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this using aggregation:

```
SELECT a_id
FROM tableB
GROUP BY a_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```